# Erro in importing 'PunktWordTokenizer'

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to tokenize sentences using `nltk.tokenize`, but the following error occurs when I run the code:

> cannot import name 'PunktWordTokenizer'.

I tried to find a solution from different sources but couldn't come up with any solution. I tried using [github-issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/920) but without success.

```
from nltk.tokenize import PunktWordTokenizer
tokenizer = PunktWordTokenizer()
tokenizer.tokenize("Can't is a contraction.")
```

I expected the tokenised sentences but an error occurred.

Comment: What version of nltk did you install?

Comment: See this related issue from nltk's github: [Cannot Import PunktWordTokenizer in nltk 3.3](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2122)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear which tokenizer you want. There isn't one called `PunktWordTokenizer` anymore. It was internal and was not intended to be public. Which is why you can't import that name. The two classes with names closest to that are called `WordPunctTokenizer` and  `PunktSentenceTokenizer`.

Import the right name and it will work:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
>>> tokenizer.tokenize("Can't is a contraction.")
['Can', "'", 't', 'is', 'a', 'contraction', '.']
```

Since you say you are looking for *tokenized sentences*, then maybe it is the other you want:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer()
>>> tokenizer.tokenize("Can't is a contraction.")
["Can't is a contraction."]
>>> tokenizer.tokenize("Can't is a contraction. So is hadn't.")
["Can't is a contraction.", "So is hadn't."]
```